# ERROR: Out of memory

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I'm getting an Out Of Memory error when running a program with an input of ~5M obs. and 153 variables.

When running the same program on ~40,000 obs.  - program executes and completes great.
When I try to increment number of input obs. to more than 100K - I get an error : Out of memory.

I tried to follow the below tips and uncheck few boxes:

```
1.Tools ► Options ► Results General ► deselect all Result Formats.
2.Tools ► Options ► Results General ► deselect Open generated data/results automatically.
3.Tools ► Options ► Results General ► deselect Link handcoded ODS results.
4.Tools ► Options ► SAS Programs ► deselect Automatically direct results back to SAS Enterprise Guide.
```

Still - Not working.

I use Enterprise Guide 5.1 
but eventually will insert the working code into a User Written Code transformation on Data Integration Studio 4.6.

Does anyone have a clue how to get this program work?

***edited***

This is the piece of code causes the error messaage:

```
 data _null_;
        set all_include_Stornos ;
        IF TREATMENT_IND = 1 AND DDS_ROW_IND NE 1 THEN DO;
        CALL EXECUTE ('%STORNO_TKUFA ('||POLICY_RK||');');
        CALL EXECUTE ('%UPDATE (STORNO_TKUFA_CUMULATE);');
        END;
        IF TREATMENT_IND in (4) AND DDS_ROW_IND NE 1  THEN DO;

            CALL EXECUTE ('%HAKPAA ('||POLICY_RK||','||POLICY_VERSION||');');
            call execute ('%UPDATE(HAKPAA_CUMULATE);');


        END;

        IF TREATMENT_IND  = 5  AND DDS_ROW_IND NE 1  and count_bitul_no <2  or (count_bitul_no >1 and max_bitul_ver = policy_verSion ) THEN DO;
            CALL EXECUTE ('%BITUL ('||POLICY_RK||','||POLICY_VERSION||');');
            CALL EXECUTE ('%UPDATE(BITUL_CUMULATE);');

        END;

        IF TREATMENT_IND = 6 AND DDS_ROW_IND NE 1  THEN DO;
        CALL EXECUTE ('%LAST_STATE ('||POLICY_RK||','||POLICY_VERSION||');'); 
        CALL EXECUTE ('%UPDATE (LAST_STATE_calc);');
        END;

        IF DDS_ROW_IND NE 1 and ((PREV_TREATMENT_IND = 4 AND TREATMENT_IND NOT IN (1,2,5)) or treatment_ind = 3) THEN DO;
            CALL EXECUTE ('%HAFSHARA ('||POLICY_RK||','||POLICY_VERSION||');');
            CALL EXECUTE ('%UPDATE (HAFSHARA_CUMULATE);');
        END;

            IF TREATMENT_IND = 2 AND POLICY_VERSION - 1 = max_bitul_ver AND DDS_ROW_IND NE 1  THEN DO;
        CALL EXECUTE ('%STORNO_BITUL ('||POLICY_RK||','||POLICY_VERSION||');');
        CALL EXECUTE ('%UPDATE (STORNO_BITUL_CUMULATE);');
        END;
RUN;
```

and these are 2 macros (shortened) executed when treatment_ind = 5:

```
%macro BITUL (pol_rk , pol_ver );


    proc sql;
    create table macro_BITUL
    as select * from all_include_Stornos
    where policy_rk = &pol_rk
    and treatment_ind_5 = &pol_ver 
    order by policy_rk, policy_version;
    quit;



    data BITUL_calc;
    set macro_BITUL;
    BY POLICY_RK;

    IF LAST.policy_rk THEN ACT_DAILY_AMT_END_DT = POLICY_VERSION_END_DT;
            ELSE ACT_DAILY_AMT_END_DT = NEXT_POLICY_VERSION_START_DT; 

    VERSION_EXPOSURE_DAYS_NO = ACT_DAILY_AMT_END_DT - ACT_DAILY_AMT_START_DT + 1;

    BITUL_DURATION =  (POLICY_EXPIRATION_DT_5 - POLICY_VERSION_START_DT + 1) / (POLICY_VERSION_END_DT_5 - POLICY_VERSION_START_DT + 1);

    GAINED_NET_PREMIUM_V_AMT  = NET_PREMIUM_V_AMT *BITUL_DURATION;
    .
    .
    .
    GAINED_NET_COMMISION_B_IB_V_AMT = PRODUCR_B_NET_COMM_IB_V_AMT * BITUL_DURATION; 
    run;

    /**/


    PROC SQL;
    CREATE TABLE TOTAL_GAINED AS 
    SELECT POLICY_RK,
    SUM(GAINED_NET_PREMIUM_V_AMT) AS TOT_GAINED_NET_PREMIUM_V_AMT,
    SUM(GAINED_NET_FEES_V_AMT) AS TOT_GAINED_NET_FEES_V_AMT,
    .
    .
    .
    SUM(GAINED_NET_COMMISION_B_IB_V_AMT) AS TOT_GAINED_NET_COMMN_B_IB_V_AMT 

    FROM BITUL_calc
    GROUP BY POLICY_RK;
    QUIT;

    PROC SQL;
    CREATE TABLE BITUL_calc_AND_TOTALS AS
    SELECT A.* , 
    TOT_GAINED_NET_PREMIUM_V_AMT,
    .
    .
    JOIN TOTAL_GAINED AS B
    ON
    (A.POLICY_rK = B.POLICY_RK
    )order  by policy_rk, policy_version;
    QUIT;




    DATA bitul_CALCULATED;
    SET BITUL_calc_AND_TOTALS;
    IF TOT_GAINED_NET_PREMIUM_V_AMT = 0 THEN CALCULATED_NET_PREMIUM_V_AMT = 0; 
        ELSE CALCULATED_NET_PREMIUM_V_AMT = NET_PREMIUM_AMT_5 * GAINED_NET_PREMIUM_V_AMT / TOT_GAINED_NET_PREMIUM_V_AMT;
    .
    .
        ELSE CALC_NET_COMMISION_B_IB_V_AMT = PRODUCR_B_NET_COMM_IB_AMT_5 * GAINED_NET_COMMISION_B_IB_V_AMT / TOT_GAINED_NET_COMMN_B_IB_V_AMT;


    .
    .
    .
    .
    .


    run;

    DATA BITUL_CUMULATE;
    SET bitul_CALCULATED;
.
.
.
.
.
.
run;    

%mend ;




%MACRO UPDATE (TABLE_NAME);
        PROC SQL;
            DELETE FROM all_include_Stornos
            WHERE CATS(POLICY_RK,POLICY_VERSION) IN ( SELECT CATS(POLICY_RK,POLICY_VERSION) FROM     &TABLE_NAME);
            INSERT INTO all_include_Stornos
select *    FROM &TABLE_NAME
            ;QUIT;

/*          PROC SORT DATA=all_include_Stornos OUT=all_include_Stornos; BY POLICY_RK     POLICY_VERSION;RUN;*/

%MEND;
```

Comment: I'm not an expert with EG, but have you tried following the other methods here http://support.sas.com/kb/40/480.html

Comment: I did actually. Got an error message... SAS could'nt find the path or something like this

Comment: What kind of procs does it contain? Could be that your system somehow fails to handle the sort. Or that you are doing a proc freq on something with an enormous amount of variables. Or that you are using a procedure that is generating an unmanagable flood of output. Or...

Comment: It is basically a realy long program... No proc freq. 143 variables. I don't think it's too much to handle.

Comment: Well, if it is really long, you better run it in smaller pieces. That way, you can identify where it goes wrong. Most memory problems can be solved by taking a slightly different approach or even by adding a single keyword in some cases. But of course, you need to pinpoint the spot where it fails.

Comment: Thing is, program runs great with 80k observations on imput. I don't see anything special written in log besides the above message, so  I can't really tell when it falls.

Comment: In my experience, the usual suspects tend to be large hash merges, or using proc means/summary with class statements that span millions of levels, but this might be something totally different. What memsize and sortsize options do you have set, and how much memory does your machine have?

Comment: How do  I found out the sortsize\memsize set for my machine?

Comment: Well, if you run it step by step with the 5M observations, you will know when it fails. E.g., you do it one data step/proc at a time. If you passed the first 12 data steps/procs and then you get the error when you ran the 13th, you know that it is the 13th data step/proc that is too heavy. You can then provide us with that piece of code and we might be able to give more targeted help. Right now, everybody is just playing a guessing game. Also, even if someone provides you with a correct suggestion, you will still need to find the location in the code where you need to intervene.

Comment: I know on which data step it throws me out. Thing is, it's a data _null_ calls different macros according to if statements. When I run the code with an input of 80K observations, the table I work on is about 50M. When I run the same process with an input of ~400K observations, I see table weights ~500M. I don't get any errors of inefficient work space or anything else. just thrown out of the server with an out of memory error. I edited my post and inserted the data _null_ I am talking about. Hopefully now it'll make more sence to you. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Thank you, this already helps quite a bit. You can actually get even more precise info by enabling some extra log information on macro's: -> options mprint mlogic symbolgen mprintnest mlogicnest symbolgen; <-. While the log will probably become huge (best send it to a file), you could pinpoint the exact macro where it goes wrong. But what you added to the question already helps a lot. Also, the fact that the data grows to 500M rows helps explain too.

Comment: I use the options mprint mlogic symbolgen mprintnest mlogicnest symbolgen. It's not useful at all. All I can tell from the log is, the program doesn't enter any macro. The fact no table should have been created using the macro was actually created, helps too.

Comment: Do i understand correctly that none of the call execute code has been written? (and hence executed)

Comment: `proc options group=memory;
run;` will show you your memory-related options including `SORTSIZE` and `MEMSIZE`.

Comment: That code gives me nightmares...

Comment: Here's a simpler demonstration of the problem: `%macro blah;
  data _null_;
    x = 1;
  run;
%mend;

data _null_;
  do i = 1 to 5 * 1000000;
    call execute('%blah;');
  end;
run;`  Running that will crash SAS with an `Out of memory` exception.  No great surprise.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this: "I know on which data step it throws me out. Thing is, it's a data null calls different macros according to if statements."

Take a look at how `Call Execute` works. (http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi22/CODERS/PAPER70.PDF will be helpful)

Essentially, `Call Execute` will parse the macro code immediately, but it queues up the resulting SAS steps until after the current data step finishes. In other words, you are potentially building up millions upon millions of lines of SAS code in memory that SAS is just storing up to be executed when that `data _null_;` step finishes. Eventually, this gets so large that SAS just craps out.

How to deal with this? Simply write a macro to break the `data _null_;` step into chunks. You can use `proc sql` to select the number of records in `all_include_Stornos` into a macro variable. Then use a macro loop to run the data step multiple times, using `firstobs` and `obs` to hit only a portion of the data each time. That way, you can keep the buffer that's built up by `call execute` down to a reasonable size. That should prevent you from running out of memory.

Comment: I was actually thinking of such solution, but I have a problem I couldn't get an answer for. I cannot allow a situation I have an RK spreaded in more than 1 chunk. No idea how to solve this

Comment: Sort it, assign an value to blocks of rows ensuring you don't break an ID across different blocks, then process 1 block at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the edit and your comment, i suspect that the 'order by' and/or 'proc sort' parts just cannot handle the volume on the system it is running.

50M is a lot of records, but still manageable by most.
But if your data grows to 500M records, it might be too much.

I recall a client I had a while ago where the dataset was 120M rows and (iirc) +-300 variables and we did get similar issues.

Luckily, there are some ways to handle larger amounts of data in a sort.

**1. Use the tagsort option**

You can add tagsort as an option to the proc sort statement. In that case, SAS only sorts using the columns that are in the by statement and attaches the remaining part of the records afterwards. It is less resource-intensive, but of course, it is slower.

**2. Use indexes for by statements**

If you need the data to be in a particular order for a by statement later on in a proc/data step, you can create an index on these variables instead of sorting the data. My experience is that this will allow SAS to cope with larger datasets as well. Of course, it is slower, it consumes more space (for the index) and you need to take into account the existence (and destruction) of indexes.

**3. Split the dataset, sort the parts and stitch everything together afterwards**

A final method (which is probably preferrable to option 2 in many cases) is to:

1. Split the dataset into smaller datasets.
2. Sort each smaller dataset.
3. Bring everything back together again by using a simple data step. (put all the smaller datasets in the set statement and use the by statement you sorted on)

This list method (and tagsort) are explained here: http://www.nesug.org/Proceedings/nesug12/cc/cc36.pdf

Note that all these methods require you to get rid of any order by and follow up those proc sql pieces with the appropriate sort procedure.

Comment: `PROC SORT` will not run out of memory, so long as `OPTION SORTSIZE` is not set above the amount of memory available; it will simply use disk.

Comment: Thank you guys for your replies. I tried to break the macro into pieces, ran it line by line until it collapsed. What I saw is, an "out of memory" error. No disconnect this time, on a simple line of code, nothing suspicious. When I put that line and all lines after in comments - macro doesn't give me any error. So I guess it IS a memory issue after all. I used the proc options group=memory; run; as recommended, gave a MEMSIZE=1073741824. What weird is, on server , MEMSIZE is geven the value of 4GB in the configuration file... so now I'm stuck, and confused

Comment: OK. so memory issue was fixed. MEMSIZE is now 4GB, but program still fails to finish. I'm running out options

Comment: What do you mean with fails to finish? You get the same error? A different error? Or does it run for an eternity? (or still something else)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check how much disk space is assigned to your sas session and sorting. The options for these are called MEMSIZE and SORTSIZE

Run this code and you will see the values in the log in bytes:

```
proc options group=memory option=(memsize sortsize) ; run;
```

I recommend to add this line as the first line in your code to assign MAX space to sort size: `options  sortsize=MAX;` and see if this solved the issue.

Otherwise you can change the MEMSIZE to MAX , follow steps in this [post](http://proc-x.com/2013/01/sas-administration-change-the-options-to-get-more-performance/).

Answer (score 0):

Either add `%nrstr()` into your CALL EXECUTE statements.

```
CALL EXECUTE ('%nrstr(%STORNO_TKUFA) ('||POLICY_RK||');');
CALL EXECUTE ('%nrstr(%UPDATE) (STORNO_TKUFA_CUMULATE);');
```

Or perhaps better change your data _null_ step to generate a file with the code and %include the file.

```
filename code temp;
data _null_;
  set all_include_Stornos ;
  IF TREATMENT_IND = 1 AND DDS_ROW_IND NE 1 THEN DO;
    put '%STORNO_TKUFA (' POLICY_RK ');';
    put '%UPDATE (STORNO_TKUFA_CUMULATE);';
...
RUN;
%include code ;
```